# How do I list user rights and group memeberships of a domain user with Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I would like to list all the windows group memberships of a domain user using powershell. How can I do this?

Comment: what you mean for "user rights"?

Comment: @Christian Rereading my post I will edit it and include only Windows Group memberships. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you mean by "list all user rights" - but group membership is straightforward from your domain:

```
$de = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$ds = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($de)
$ds.Filter = "(&(objectClass=User)(sAMAccountName=goyuix))"
$user = $ds.FindOne()
$user.Properties.memberof
```

The `memberof` property should contain a list of all the group memberships for that account. You would need to update the `Filter` to use the appropriate login rather than my hard-coded user.

Comment: nested groups are not listed in memberof. Use quest module for cmdlets to achieve all groups membership

Answer (score 1):

gyurisc! Is it that you mean?

```
function Get-ProfilesList {
  $hive = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"

  #проверка нужна лишь на время отладки
  if (Test-Path $hive) {
    gci $hive | % -b {$prof = @()} -p {$dest = "" | select UserName, Sid, ProfilePath
    $dest.Sid = $_.PSChildName
    $dest.ProfilePath = (gp ($hive + "\" + $_.PSChildName)).ProfileImagePath
    $dest.UserName = Split-Path $dest.ProfilePath -leaf
    $prof += $dest
    } -end {$prof}
  }
}

Get-ProfilesList | ft -auto
```